How do I add multiple nodes at the same time to an existing cluster?
We have a 9 node Cassandra (V3.11) cluster and we want to add another 10 nodes to this cluster. Can we add all the 10 nodes to the cluster at the same time (with auto bootstrap parameter set to false)? And to balance the data to the newly added nodes, should we run repair or rebuild command? And can we run them on multiple machines at the same time?
Each of the existing nodes in the cluster has around 14TB disk space and out of which 11TB is already used. When we tried to add a new node, it was able to get around 5TB is around 5 days and after that the speed reduced considerably (to 200GB per day). Instead of adding one at a time, can we add all together and rebalance the data by any command?
Any pointers will be highly appreciated!

If it gets slow or hung, you could stop it and try a nodetool bootstrap resume. That's worth trying to get the streaming process to complete.
Erick makes a great point about how joining a node w/ auto_bootstrap: false will allow the new node to attempt to serve requests before it has all of the data. But, as long as your RF is 3 or more (or you query at a consistency of ONE), you might be ok to take that approach one node at a time.
I've done this in the past when the joining/streaming process gets hung of, slows down, or takes too long. Basically, you join the new node w/ auto_bootstrap: false. It joins, and attempts to participate in supporting read requests, but that's ok since you have other replicas to help with that. Then, on the new node you run a nodetool rebuild -- <your-source-datacenter-here>.
Rebuild is sometimes the better option over a repair (assuming that you have another data center to pull data from). You can then monitor its progress by running nodetool netstats | grep Already, which returns a status by each node streaming, specifying completion progress in terms of # of files streamed.
If you have to restart the process, rebuild will also pick up where it left off.

It's not possible to bootstrap multiple nodes at the same time.
When node A is bootstrapping, it is in the process of taking over ownership of a range(s) of tokens and requests data from replicas. Until it has finished receiving all the data, it isn't able to serve read requests so can't take full ownership yet.
If you attempt to bootstrap another node B while node A is still joining the cluster, the remaining nodes will reject the operation because of the risk that node B takes over a token range that is being taken over by node A. Allowing node B to do so can result in inconsistent range movement, particularly if node A fails to complete bootstrapping.
It is also a bad idea to set auto_bootstrap: false to add nodes to an existing DC because they won't request data (bootstrap) from other replicas BUT will immediately serve read requests despite not having any data.
Unfortunately, there is no magic pill that will let you add nodes any quicker. It is the price you have to pay for having very dense nodes (lots of data). For this reason, we recommend keeping nodes density low at around 1TB each so it is easier to add/repair/decommission nodes. Cheers!
